# Can Absolute agent monitor VPN traffic?

Tags: vpn

I have a pc with absolute agent (computrace) installed, will it be able to monitor traffic send over a private VPN? I.E. Not a free VPN, or will it still capture history via the browser history on the pc?

Comment: I am not familiar with that product, but when it runs on your local machine and monitors your network activity, then the software would have to take special measures to *not* monitor traffic which is going to go through a VPN connection.

Comment: Have you asked the vendor?

Comment: We are trying to prevent users from bypassing the software when working remotely, however, the vendor docs have no such info available. The general understanding is that it will still capture the history as this is stored on the machine itself, while data sent over VPN is encrypted, the request isn't, this is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out it can monitor all online activity as requests are only encrypted once submitted and seeing that the software resides on the machine it already captures the browser history before encryption is applied.

Excellent software!

Comment: iThis smells like spam. On an IS site some 3rd party thing that monitors and logs everything you do isn't exactly what we define as "excellent".